# Can i restrict windows login using a java program?

Tags: java, login-script

I want to restrict the windows login for a system using a java code so that i can perform a specific number of tasks before the user can logon to the system.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Probably not, you will need at least a small program in C (or something as low level as that) to start the JVM and load your Java program into it.

Comment: Nope, where would java run? on JVM? how would JVM run? ??

Comment: This is not a matter of *java code*. You have to configure the system to execute a jvm with your application before the system is ready to allow people to login.

Comment: what kind of tasks? if they can be handled by a Batch Script. I would recommend a Batch (y)

Comment: before *any* user can log in, or some specific user? which windows?

Answer (score 0):

Any java program will need a JVM to run. Right?

So before executing your ***Java Code*** you need to run a JVM and load your program on it.

I dont Know what your *Java Code* does or how you are writing it. I am assuming that you know how you will execute your *Tasks* and then let the user login ( A layman approach would be, disable the KeyInput and mouseInputs ,thus user wont be able to do anything until your program finishes).

Now coming back to how to start a JVM and load your code to it.

Write a `Batch` , that starts `JVM` and then start your java program from that `Batch`